# Using v-edit-dialog with components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

i had a question about the v-edit-dialog component that vuetify offers. So, the way i am rendering my v-data-table is such that i am importing a component with props into a template slot. According to the documentation [link](https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables), it seems like the data table has to be rendered directly, like this [codepen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/PoYjLjX).

So i am not sure how i can make the v-edit-dialog work using my approach.

Here is what my code looks like:-

```
  <template>
    <v-data-table>
       <template v-slot:items="props">
          <my-component 
            :protein="props.item.protein"
            :carbs="props.item.carbs" 
            :fats = "props.item.fats"
            :iron="props.item.iron"/>
       </template>
    <v-data-table>
  </template>
```

I am sorry guys, i don't know how i can duplicate this issue but i hope you get  some idea. Again, thank you in advance.

Comment: Your codepen link is invalid. Also, please use the built in code-playground on stackoverflow for this instead of codepen, makes it easier to see it all on one site.

Comment: @SølveTornøe I have updated the codepen link. not sure what happened there.

Comment: I don't see your problem in your question. What is it you are trying to achieve? What is your approach with v-edit-dialog? The codepen looks like it works?

Comment: Right now they are rendering the fields in a single component, So it is easy to wrap the fields inside a v-edit-dialog example proteins, carbs etc but i am importing a separate component and i am passing props to achieve my proteins, carbs etc fields. So how can i wrap my props inside a v-edit-dialog?

Comment: You want to have a `v-edit-dialog` inside your `my-component` that uses the props `protein` and  `carbs`?

Comment: Yes, exactly and more so if i have more props, how can i wrap only proteins and carbs in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the [documentation for component props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html).

What you have done by now is correct and should work, only if you have setup your component `my-component` correctly:

```
<!-- my-component example -->
<template>
  <v-edit-dialog :return-value.sync="protein">
   {{ protein }}
   <template v-slot:input>
      <v-text-field
       v-model="protein"
       :rules="[max25chars]"
       label="Edit"
       single-line
       counter
      />
   </template>
 </v-edit-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'my-component',
  props: {
    protein: {
       type: String,
       default: '',
    }, //... the rest of the props you want to access
  },
}
</script>
```

In order to make the protein and other props edit/mutate/update your `props.item.protein` etc, you have to add a [sync modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) to the prop.

```
  <template>
    <v-data-table>
       <template v-slot:items="props">
          <my-component 
            :protein.sync="props.item.protein"
            :carbs.sync="props.item.carbs" 
            :fats.sync="props.item.fats"
            :iron.sync="props.item.iron"/>
       </template>
    <v-data-table>
  </template>
```

Else, you will get a vue error "you should not mutate an prop directly"

Comment: Boom. this is exactly what i wanted. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

```
<template v-slot:items="props">. 
for this eazy right is 
<template v-slot:items="{ item }">
<my-component 
            {{item. protein}}
```